# ionic 3 action sheet title translation

Tags: angular, ionic3, ngx-translate

i am using action sheet and ngx translate plugin in my ionic 3 angular app.

like everywhere else in my app the translation for action sheet doesn't work if i specify like below then whole of it is considered as string.

```
this.actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
          title: "{{'SEND' | translate }}",
          buttons: [
```

and if i specify without double quotes then it's not accepted.

so what should be the correct way to pass the translated title to this ?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm looking for this myself

Answer (score 0):

you can use translate before:

var titletext = this.translate.instant('SEND');
this.actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
          title: titletext,